# array de numero a boleanos

Tags: javascript, array, map, booleano

estoy intentando crear un array de booleanos (a2) en funcion a un array de numeros (a) segun si el valor de cada uno de los elementos (x) del array (a) es mayor o menor a un numero (limit), este es mi codigo

```
let a2 = []
a2 = a.map(x => {
    if (x <= limit) {
        console.log(`${x} es menor que ${limit}`)
        a2.push(true)
    } else {
        console.log(`${x} es mayor que ${limit}`)
        a2.push(false)
    }
});
console.log(a2)
```

el problema es que me devuelde un array de elementos undefinded, he intendado poner returns antes de cada push, pero en ese caso me devuelve un array del estilo [0,1,2,3...]

Answer (score 2):

puede hacerlo asi:

```js
let a2 = [];
let limit = 2;
let a =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
a2 = a.map(x => {
    if (x <= limit) {
        console.log(`${x} es menor que ${limit}`)
        // retornamos para que se asigne a a2
        return true
    } else {
        console.log(`${x} es mayor que ${limit}`)
        // retornamos para que se asigne a a2
        return false
    }
});
console.log(a2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas, aunque veo que ya te han contestado te comento el error de tu código, estas intentando usar el método `map()` como un `forEach()` según veo.

El método `map()` aplica una función a cada elemento del array y devuelve un nuevo array, por lo que es normal que te salga `undefined` ya que no tenias ningún `return`

Te dejo la documentación:

- [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

**Te dejo los dos ejemplos:**

```js
let a2 = []
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let limit = 2

// Usando map
a2 = a.map(x => {
    if (x <= limit) {
        console.log(`${x} es menor que ${limit}`)
        return true
    } else {
        console.log(`${x} es mayor que ${limit}`)
        return false
    }
});

console.log(a2)
```

```js
let a2 = []
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let limit = 2

// Usando forEach
a.forEach(x => {
    if (x <= limit) {
        console.log(`${x} es menor que ${limit}`)
        a2.push(true)
    } else {
        console.log(`${x} es mayor que ${limit}`)
        a2.push(false)
    }
})

console.log(a2)
```